# Count Number of Rows based on Parameter. (Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I need to count the number of rows depending on the week and type of the data. I have the excel formula but I want to make it as a VB code yet I don't have that much idea and it is not working.

```
=IF(AND($N$4="All",$N$5="All"),SUM(('SD'!$I$2:$I$99538='Source'!$B6)*('SD'!$A$2:$A$99538='Source'!C$5)),IF(AND($N$4="All",$N$5<>"All"),SUM(('SD'!$I$2:$I$99538='Source'!$B6)*('SD'!$A$2:$A$99538='Source'!C$5)*('SD'!$B$2:$B$99538='Source'!$N$5)),IF(AND($N$4<>"All",$N$5="All"),SUM(('SD'!$I$2:$I$99538='Source'!$B6)*('SD'!$A$2:$A$99538='Source'!C$5)*('SD'!$K$2:$K$99538='Source'!$N$4)),IF(AND($N$4<>"All",$N$5<>"All"),SUM(('SD'!$I$2:$I$99538='Source'!$B6)*('SD'!$A$2:$A$99538='Source'!C$5)*('SD Raised'!$B$2:$B$99538='Source'!$N$5)*('SD'!$K$2:$K$1048576='Source'!$N$4))))))
```

I have a sheet where in all datas are captured (SD) and the second one will be the sheet(Source) where i need to count the number of rows available based on the parameter as follow; The week where data belongs and the category of the data.

Edit:
This formula* does not count the data i needed to count. And if possible I want to make it as a VBA code.

This is where the counted data should go. "Weeks are changing depending on the dropdown iput (Max of 4 weeks below from the selected week)"

[image: Report]

This image shows the data where i need to capture and count the number of category based on the weeks and category. (Sample only)

[image: source]

Comment: what is your question now ? what have you tried, what exactly should it do ? please specify your question

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo Sorry for that, but this code isn't working.

Comment: Is it just my web page? I can't see any code ... just an Excel formula.

Answer (score 0):

so i have to guess a bit what you want, but if you want to Count specific rows in Excel vba you can use something like this:

```
Dim allRows As Variant
Dim i As Long

Dim count as Long
count = 0

allRows = Tabelle5.Range("A" & start_row, end_column & last_row)

For i = 1 To UBound(allRows)
    If allRows(i, 1) = *category* and allRows(i,2) = *week* Then
        count = count + 1
    End If
Next
```

To find right range, there are multiple possible solution. I use this, maybe it is not the best, but works fine for me:

```
Private Function last_row() As Integer
 Dim rangeObj As Range
 Set rangeObj = Tabelle5.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
 If rangeObj Is Nothing Then
    last_row = start_row
 Else
    last_row = rangeObj.row
 End If
End Function

Public Function start_row() As Integer
    start_row = 2
End Function
```

Comment: I've added images for further reference.

Comment: yes that should be possible, with what i have posted, just make a function out of it, with category and week as parameter

Comment: i believe this will work but have a few more question since i need to set the range, yet the data's needed such as week and category are in A2- and I2-, range should be maximize since every week data are being added.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, if it's the right point you're hitting DoktorOSwaldo, better use the Range().Rows.Count property rather than scrolling through allRows.
Hope this helps.

Hadi

Comment: Posts that do not directly answer (or attempt to answer) OP's question should be posted as a comment to the post you are replying to.

Comment: then he would have to filter the range, and a range with non continous cells, only gives Problems with the row.Count. But i see your Point, anyway Looping throught an Array, like it is done is quite fast.